# Solve for approximate solution using Newtons Method: $x^5-3x+3=0$

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble finding the approximate solution for this particular problem using Newton's Method. Can this problem even be correctly approximated using Newton's Method? For some reason I am not getting closer to any solution.

My $x$ values are as shown:
$x_1 = 1$
$x_2 = 0.5$
$x_3 = 1.07$
$x_4 = 0.7343$
$x_5 = 1.34$
$x_6 = 1.088$

As you can see they are all over the place, not giving any indication of an approximate answer.

WolphramAlpha gave me the answer of $x = -1.49577$

I have been looking over my work for the past hour and can't figure out why I'm not getting an answer. How do I solve this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Newton's law? Perhaps you mean [Newton–Raphson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I meant Newton's Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your guess doesn't work is that $f'(x)=5x^4-3$ has a root, $\sqrt[4]{\frac{3}{5}}$ between $0$ and $1$. You need to avoid points where $f'(x)=0$

We see it has another real root is $(-1,0)$ and $f(-1)$ is positive, and the function is increasing at that point. Thus the root of $f(x)$ must lie somewhere less than $-1$.

We start with our first guess at $x=-1$.

After $7$ iterations,

$$x=-1.4966242763620632$$

Yes that was done in python, you can do about 4 iterations by hand I think.

Comment: Thank you!The entire time, I was thinking "If only my x1 was negative, I would probably have the right answer" haha, but I am still not clear on how you decided to use negative. So tell me if this is right, you set the derivative equal to 0 to get the root, which told you its between 0 and 1. Which means, my first guess can't be between [0,1]? So then we say since its an even root (fourth root), it gave us + or - as an answer. And since we cant choose the positive value between [0,1], then we know the negative root is between [-1,0]?..

Comment: The derivative has a root at $-\sqrt[4]{3/5}\approx-.88$ as well, so $x=-1$ may not be the best place to start either.  Starting at $x=-3/2$ goes to $-178/119\approx-1.495798$ in one step.

Comment: @BarryCipra I agree. I went a little lazy because I had python handy. My point was that you only need to make sure that there are no roots of $f'(x)$ between your original guess and the true root. Otherwise it wont work.

Comment: @Dylan sorry I dont exactly understand your question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @BarryCipra although If you guess $x=-3/2$, you don't need newton's method. $x=-1.5$ is already accurate enough, imo.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes, that is what I was wondering, because I knew + or - the root would set f'(x)=0. But what your saying is that the first guess cant be between [-1,0] or [0,1] because it will set the derivative equal to zero? and that's why you chose -3/2 (just outside of -1)? but what about +3/2? are all positives not a valid first guess?

Comment: @Sabysachi I am just trying to figure out how you concluded the first guess to be a negative rather than a positive

Comment: @Dylan do you understand how the approximation method works? I mean do you have a mental image of what's going on?

Comment: @Sabyasachi From my understanding, it allows us to get closer and closer to a solution of a given fuction(e.g. x^2-2=0 would approximate very close to sqrt(2).

Comment: @Dylan yes you're right. You should see [the animated diagram to the right here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Description). to see what is actually happening. Watch it and tell me if you understand why we can't take a guess near a point where the slope is zero.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Right, because then we would not be able to retrieve a following x value. Perhaps I am going in circles here and I really appreciate all your help, but by choosing a negative value for the first guess, we will essentially be working our way from left-to-right along the x-axis, correct? But what if I started my guess at 3/2, that does not make the derivative = 0 just as -3/2 doesn't.. then we would be working from right-to-left. The only reason I say this, is because this is how I will think on my exam next week and obviously its the wrong way of thinking.

Comment: @Dylan, $f(-1)=5$ and $f(-2)=-23$, so there's a root in the interval $[-2,-1]$.  I just started at the midpoint.  There are actually lots of subtleties involved in Newton's method.  For example, try finding a root of $f(x)=x^3-5x$ starting at $x=1$.

Comment: @Dylan I understand your problem. The point is, you see, you need to make sure that there is no point between your guess and the real root, such that $f'(x)=0$. I made sure of this, my seeing that the two roots of $f'$ are in $(-1,1)$(tell me if you dont understand this part), and the actual root of $f$ must be less than $-1$

Comment: @Sabyasachi I understand that anything between (-1,1) should not be used. I think its making sense. The reason that the actual root of F has to be less than -1 and cannot be greater than 1 is simply because by looking at the graph, when we move from right-to-left there will be a value that will make  f '(x) = 0? or is there a calculation that told you this? E.g. given we got +/-(fourth root(3/5)) = approx. .8011 then can we say f(.8011) = .92 which is in (-1,1) so it cannot be used. and f(-.8011) = 5.07 which is outside of (-1,1), thus our Real root must be negative and therefore less than -1?

Comment: @Dylan You can check that $f(-1)$ is positive, and $f(-2)$ is negative. Now mean value theorem.